# Order a PHP array based on contents

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => post4.post
    [3] => post7.post
    [4] => post5.post
    [5] => post3.post
    [6] => post6.post
    [7] => post1.post
    [8] => post2.post
)
```

How could I arrange it so it could look like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => post7.post
    [1] => post6.post
    [2] => post5.post
    [3] => post4.post
    [4] => post3.post
    [5] => post2.post
    [6] => post1.post
)
```

The array has a list of the files contained in a folder. In my local server looks like the second example but on a standard server looks like the first one.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsort($array)` will sort an array in reverse/descending order (from high to low).

For future reference use this page (http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) to identify the most suited array sorting method for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [**`rsort`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php).

PHP has great documentation. I suggest you have a look at the [*array functions*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) and the [*Sorting Arrays*](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) article (which can be easily find via Google ;))

Comment: Ahh beat me to it! +1 for speediness

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `rsort` because it will reassign array indexes. Instead use **[arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)**.

Comment: From his example it looks like he wants to reassign the indexes.

Comment: I could swear the indexes were maintained when I first read the question.